# Trying to update an existing element inside my useState causes to create another element with the same ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

So, this code block is giving me some serious trouble and I can't figure out how to fix it myself.
It's supposed to set an object to an array of objects on my useState if it has a unique ID, instead what it does is generate a new object with the same ID everytime I update my components.

Here's the console log of my useState
[image]

```
function CreateQuestionSurvey({data, setData}) {
 const [questionType, setQuestionType] = useState("");
 const questionTypeString = useRef()
 const [question,setQuestion] = useState("")
 const [questionAnswers, setQuestionAnswers] = useState()

 const [object, setObject] = useState({
    'question': '', 
    'type':'',
    'possibleAnswers' : '',
    'id': crypto.randomUUID()
 })
console.log('setObject', object);
useEffect(() =>{
  const updatedObject = { ...object ,
        'question': question, 
        'type':questionTypeString.current?.value,
        'possibleAnswers' : questionAnswers,
        }

  setObject(updatedObject)

 },[question,questionAnswers,questionType,questionTypeString])


 useEffect(()=>{
  const existingObjectIndex = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === object.id);
  console.log(existingObjectIndex);

  if (existingObjectIndex == -1) {
    setData(prevArray => [...prevArray, object]);
  } else {
      setData(prevArray => {
        const updatedArray = [...prevArray];
        updatedArray[existingObjectIndex] = { ...prevArray[existingObjectIndex], object };
        return updatedArray;
      });
  }
 },[object])
}
```

existingObjectIndex always returns "-1"

Also tried this with different result, but still not what I want.

```
// useEffect(()=>{

// const index = data.findIndex((i)=>i.id == object.id)
// console.log(index);
// if(index == -1){
//   setData([object])
// } else{
//   let newData = [...data]
//   newData = data[index] = object
//   setData(newData)
// }

// },[object])
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` effect uses `data` but does not list it in the dependency list. The search for the existing `object` will be stale. You can move the `data.findIndex(..)` into the `setData(..)` callback.

Comment: Data is a useState defined in other component.

function CreateNewSurvey() {
  const [data,setData] = useState([]) 
...
}

I pass this useState as a prop to the component in the post:
function CreateQuestionSurvey({data, setData})

So, could you please illustrate your suggestion of moving the findIndex inside setData()?

Comment: Doesn't matter where it's defined – it's not listed in the dependency list, so its value within the effect will only be updated when one of the dependencies changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can move the `findIndex` into `setData(..)`:

```js
 useEffect(()=>{
  setData(prevArray =>
    {
      const existingObjectIndex = prevArray.findIndex(obj => obj.id === object.id);
      console.log(existingObjectIndex);

      if (existingObjectIndex === -1)
        return [...prevArray, object];
      else
      {
        const updatedArray = [...prevArray];
        updatedArray[existingObjectIndex] = { ...prevArray[existingObjectIndex], ...object };
        return updatedArray;
      }
    });
 },[object])
```

Note that there also appears to be something strange going on with the value that you store in the `updatedArray` -- your supplied code has:

```
updatedArray[existingObjectIndex] = {
  ...prevArray[existingObjectIndex],
  object
};
```

I imagine that you mean to spread the `object` properties into the updated array, as in the updated `useEffect` code.